# How do I multiply a row value in a specific column in a dataframe with its own lagged value efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I have a dataframe with two columns 'actp' and 'modr': 'actp' contains an actual price series, 'modr' contains forecasted returns for the series. I want to create a third column 'modp' which takes the price series values when they exist (non NaN) or which multiplies the previous price series value 'actp' by 1 + log return ('modr') to generate a forecasted price value ('modp') and then multiply the lagged values of 'modp' by the return. It's a simple problem and easy enough to solve using a for loop. I would like to know what an efficient and elegant solution might look like as I need it to be optimised for speed and scalability.

I can accomplish this with a for loop, although it cureently doesn't add the actual value from 'actp' to 'modp' when 'actp' has a value in it.

```
for i in range(2,5):
    df['modp'].iloc[i] = df['actp'].iloc[i-1] * np.exp(df['modr'].iloc[i])
    df['actp'].iloc[i] = df['modp'].iloc[i]
```

[original data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbF1d.png)

[The expected outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AL4rs.png)

Comment: Please share samples of the data and expected output

Comment: Have you tried this using pandas [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)?

Comment: Sample data in pictures. Thanks for the shift suggestion. My title is generic but problem is a little unique in that there are a couple of conditions attached: use ACT when it exists, Multiply by lagged ACT when it is the last ACT. Multiply by self, after that

Answer (score 0):

As Dan mentioned, you can use [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)

If I understood your calculations correctly, this should be it:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'actp':[10,20,30,40],
                   'modr':[2,2,0,2]})

df['actp'] = df.actp.shift(1) * np.exp(df.modr)

print(df)
         actp  modr
0         NaN     2
1   73.890561     2
2   20.000000     0
3  221.671683     2
```

Comment: Check sample data in pictures and unfortunately `shift` here cannot be used, need `numba`